# when you add local storage what behavior do you expect?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I add local storage to my todo and I expect to save the state of the page ... I don't know how I can see that my state is saved or not
my code is below

```
var data = (function () {
    var key = 'state';
    return {
        getItems: getItems1,
        setItems: setItems1
    };

    function getItems1() {
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
        if (!value) return null;
        return value;
    };

    function setItems1(value) {
        !value && (value = {});
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    };
```

I thought that if I refresh my web it will show me the last changed in data but it did not do that

Answer (score 1):

localStorage allows web applications to store data locally within the user's browser with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available when the browser is opened again.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using localstorage and then you refresh your web it won't save the last changed in the web page ... it will just show you the last state... when you use f12 or devtools you can see how it will work on your web page... local storage is on your browser not in your server

Answer (score 0):

localstorage will show you the last state of your page it wont save the latest changes

Comment: HI, Welcome to SO, I realize that you can't comment yet, but please note for the future that simple answer like this are more appropriate for the comment section. Good luck!

Comment: @amiaali can add more details anytime , Cool!